# JS: How to prevent let double declaration? / determine if let variable is defined

Tags: javascript, variables, ecmascript-6, let

If I open JS console and write:

```
let foo;
```

and after:

```
let foo = "bar"
```

console show me (rightly)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'foo' has already been declared
```

Now... sometimes I need to inject my code inside an existing script and I don't have tool to determinate if a let variable is already defined.

I try with this code, but there is evident problem with JS scope and logic.... (comment the code)

```js
let foo; // Gloabl variable empty declare in a code far, far away 

console.log(foo); // undefined

console.log(typeof foo === "undefined"); // test that determinate if condition is true

if(typeof foo === "undefined"){
    let foo = "test";
    console.log(foo); // return "test" this means that foo as a local scope only inside this if... 
}

console.log(foo); // return undefined not test!

// and .. if I try to double declaration... 
 let foo = "bar"; //error!
```

so... How can I prevent double "let" declaration? / How to determinate if a let var is defined (declared?)

P.S 
with "var" all working fine!!!

Comment: Variables declared with `var` have function scope, and are hoisted, unlike `let` / `const`

Comment: The "existing script" is written by you?

Comment: Note that it's a *syntax error*, not a runtime error. Can you explain more about your `sometimes I need to inject my code inside an existing script`?

Comment: maybe you can put your code inside an iife so it doesnt share the same scope as the rest?

Comment: @JNF I assume that it's not my own code.

Comment: @CertainPerformance my js file is addend in another point of code for example in another PHP template file, or another example I inject code inside a page evry time a site page change in an ajax site (no DOM reload)

Comment: @r1si why can't you use a different variable name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a scope for your script. You still have access to external variable inside that scope.

```js
let toto = 42;
let foo = "bar";
   
console.log(toto);
   
//Some added script
{
    let toto = "hello world !";
    console.log(toto);
    console.log(foo);
}
//back to main script
console.log(toto);
```

You still can programmatically check if a variable exists or not using `try - catch` but this can be very tricky to declare a variable inside of `try {  } catch {  }` scopes

```js
let existingVariable = "I'm alive !";

try
{
    console.log("existingVariable exists and contains : " + existingVariable);
    console.log("UndeclaredVariable exists and contains : " + UndeclaredVariable);
}
catch (ex)
{
    if (ex instanceof ReferenceError)
    {
        console.log("Not good but I caught exception : " + ex);
    }
}
console.log("Looks like my script didn't crash :)");
```

If you don't want to create a new scope to make sure your variables don't already exist in the existing script, well... prefix them `let r1sivar_userinput`

Comment: return this:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'toto' has already been declared

Comment: sorry (I have paste two time in console), it's work and help to practice... but it's not a solution, There is a mode to determinate if a let var is defined?

Comment: Your question is *How can I prevent double "let" declaration?*, not *How to determinate if a let var is defined (declared?)*

Comment: @Cid, seems the question was meant to be _How to determinate if a let var is defined (declared)?_

Comment: @JNF yes, since he edited his question after my answer